# How do I schedule work on the ThreadPool without causing thread starvation

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool, worker

I am consuming messages from a queue, and want to invoke a message handler such that I am processing messages as fast as possible. The message handler is asynchronous, but also does some CPU work.

I have considered the following approaches:

1. On each message call Task.Run

```
    foreach (var workItem in GetWorkItemsFromQueue())
    {
        Task.Run(workItem);
    }
```

2. Same as 1, but try and not exhaust the ThreadPool

```
    foreach (var workItem in GetWorkItemsFromQueue())
    {
        while (ThreadPool.PendingWorkItemCount > 10)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }
        Task.Run(workItem);
    }
```

3. Use Parallel.ForEachAsync with 'unbounded' concurrency. Initially i was using -1 as per the docs, but changed this to int.MaxValue based on comments below

```
    var options = new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = int.MaxValue
    };
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(GetWorkItemsFromQueue(), options, async (workItem, token) =>
    {
        await workItem();
    });
```

4. Same as above, but with the default MaxDegreeOfParallelism (i.e. Environment.ProcessorCount)

```
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(GetWorkItemsFromQueue(), async (workItem, token) =>
    {
        await workItem();
    });
```

5. Use LongRunning Threads. Admittedly this isn't actually using the ThreadPool

```
    foreach (var workItem in GetWorkItemsFromQueue())
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => workItem().GetAwaiter().GetResult(), 
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning | TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness | TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
```

The most obvious approach would seem to be simply calling `Task.Run(...)` but with this approach I notice the `ThreadPool.PendingWorkItemCount` quickly growing.

Ideally I would like the `ThreadPool` **queue** to act like a `BlockingCollection` of capacity 1, which is what example 2 is trying to achieve.

Ultimately I feel like this must be a solved problem, but I'm struggling to find the solution, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I doubt approach #3 or #4 will work as it is almost doing similar to what you are doing in #1 and #2, but internally. Also in #2 Delay of 1 millisecond will only work if your tasks finishes in 1 millisecond.
Having said that, .NET manages ThreadPool starvation internally and it puts the new threads on hold unless it has more threads available for use. Are you getting any error with #1?

Comment: The issues I'm having with approach #1 is that I end up consuming all the messages from the message broker, only to then queue them up on the thread pool queue. Also, I am having some issues with thread starvation as my application also has an Asp.Net endpoint which acts as a healthcheck endpoint and it seems it doesn't respond in a timely fashion when the ThreadPool is overwhelmed.

Comment: In this case I'd suggest you to explicitly manage tasks which you do not want to execute (which you are obviously trying to do). To do that in #2, inside `ThreadPool.PendingWorkItemCount` condition, instead of delaying it by arbitrary value, collect them in a Queue and when the count is back to normal start executing them. My VS is acting crazy, I'll post an answer if it works :)

Comment: Sounds like what you actually need to do is speed up the process that deals with these requests

Comment: You've presented four approaches, of which the 1st approach doesn't work, but you haven't said whether the other three approaches work or not. Do they work? If not, what's the problem with them? It yes, what's the question?

Comment: As a side note, configuring the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1` is exactly the same as `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount`. `-1` does not mean "unbounded" for this API, it means "default". If you want unbounded concurrency, set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.MaxValue`. I don't know why the `Parallel.ForEach` and the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` treat the `-1` differently, but it is what it is.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias #2 works reasonably well. #3 & #4 work poorly because the concurrency is limited to ProcessorCount. However, as you point out, using -1 isn't unbounded (despite the docs)...and using int.MaxValue actually also works reasonably well. One approach I've tried since is using Task.Factory.StartNew(..., LongRunning) which also seems to work reasonable well, but i'm weary of using because of blog posts like this one: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: The `Task.Factory.StartNew` is OK, provided that you configure it correctly. The `scheduler` parameter should be specified explicitly, preferably to `TaskScheduler.Default`, to avoid scheduling the tasks on an ambient scheduler (`TaskScheduler.Current`). Another idea is to configure the `ThreadPool` with (for example) `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 1000);`, so that is creates new threads on demand more liberally. This, assuming that you don't mind running 1000 threads in parallel from a single process.

Comment: Btw be aware that the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.MaxValue` is truly unbounded only if the asynchronous operations are truly asynchronous. In case the asynchronous operations contain blocking/synchronous code, then this blocking code is constrained by the `ThreadPool` availability, because the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` uses the `TaskScheduler.Default` by default, which schedules work on the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I kind of expected the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.MaxValue` to behave the same as #1 as I was aware it schedules work on the ThreadPool. However, in the case of `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, the ThreadPool queue doesn't actually increase at anywhere near the same rate as it does by simply using `Task.Run()`

Comment: My expectation is that those two approaches (unbounded `Parallel.ForEachAsync` and `Task.Run`) should have the same behavior. In case you found by experimentation that it's not the case, I would suggest to post a new question containing a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the difference, and ask why this is happening.

Comment: Here's what I've been using as a test harness so far https://gist.github.com/darraghjones/e9e5e7538546ecc0a9cb92232427805a

Comment: I checked [your demo](https://gist.github.com/darraghjones/e9e5e7538546ecc0a9cb92232427805a). The `Task.Run` is indeed much better at increasing the `ThreadPool.PendingWorkItemCount` than the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`. Assuming that the whole purpose of your program is to increase the `ThreadPool.PendingWorkItemCount` as rapidly as possible, launching fire-and-forget `Task.Run` operations in a tight loop might be one of your best options. However my assumption is that your program is supposed to do something more useful than that.

Comment: Have you considered throttling using a SemaphoreSlim? Maybe so you can find the sweet spot of Tasks scheduled concurrenty.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias on the contrary, i _don't_ want to increase the `ThreadPool.PendingWorkItemCount` as I'm actually consuming messages off a message broker, so I'd rather leave then on the message queue until there is a thread available to process the message, rather than simply read all the messages of the queue, and then queue them up on the ThreadPool queue. So for my use case, `Parallel.ForEachAsync` looks like a better solution. But why it behaves differently is a bit of a mystery :/

Comment: Your demo doesn't seem like a realistic emulation of any actual scenario. Basically you are saturating the `ThreadPool`, and the CPU, by scheduling work to the `ThreadPool` in a tight loop. I don't quite understand what kind of insight/conclusion you expect to get from this demo. Honestly the whole question is not a good one. Instead of describing a problem and asking for a solution, you describe multiple solutions to an unknown problem, and then ask us to share our opinion about the merits of these various solutions. It's unlikely to get a good answer to such a question.

Comment: I think what I'm struggling to understand is what is the best way to execute work which is has both a CPU bound component AND an asynchronous component. For the former I'd probably use `Parallel.ForEach` and the later, `Task.Run()`. But when the work items is a bit of both, it's less clear what is the best approach.

Comment: Both the `Task.Run` and the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, as well as TPL Dataflow components like the `ActionBlock<T>`, are suitable for mixed sync-async scenarios. All these mechanisms understand asynchronous delegates, and all of them delegate the synchronous part of the work to the `ThreadPool`. If by "best" you mean the most efficient and most performant, they are all practically the same, since they use the same underlying engine. If you don't have any other criteria to choose (for example features like backpressure or max DOP), just throw a coin and let the coin make the choice.

Comment: Backpressure is probably the feature i'm after. That's what i was trying to convey when i mentioned that i wanted the threadpool queue to act like a blocking collection with a capacity of 1. basically i don't want to just queue all my work on the thread pool queue because that is leading to thread starvation for other parts of the program. namely my asp.net healthchecks. `Parallel.ForEachAsync` seems to behave more like what i want than `Task.Run` so I'll probably take that approach for now. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: The [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) offers the backpressure feature out of the box. Just configure it with a specific `BoundedCapacity`, and feed it with `await block.SendAsync(item)`. You can also do it with the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` and a [bounded](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel.createbounded) `Channel<T>`. Just pass the `channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync()` as the source of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, and feed the channel with `await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(item)`.

Comment: For your info, I've posted a [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/7879) for the correction of the `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` documentation, which was approved and merged today.

Comment: https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/1052415268549484545